# sqlite sorting SUM column values

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting

```
SELECT SUM(bytes),stamp_updated 
from acct 
where stamp_updated BETWEEN datetime('now', 'localtime','-7 hours') AND datetime('now', 'localtime') 
GROUP BY ip_src 
ORDER BY bytes DESC limit 10;
```

```
    48498275|2012-04-09 11:26:01
    6977282|2012-04-09 08:27:01
    1192705|2012-04-09 08:46:02
    3971336|2012-04-09 09:46:04
    1909543|2012-04-09 11:28:04
    265829|2012-04-09 09:11:02
    1234909|2012-04-09 10:28:04
    2396834|2012-04-09 11:28:02
    192638|2012-04-09 09:00:01
    30766141|2012-04-09 11:31:01
```

Why isn't the first column not getting sorted properly (DESC)?

Comment: Please, don't prefix the title with a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're ordering with your `bytes` column before they are aggregated. Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(bytes) AS total_bytes, stamp_updated 
FROM acct 
WHERE stamp_updated BETWEEN datetime('now', 'localtime','-7 hours') AND datetime('now', 'localtime') 
GROUP BY ip_src 
ORDER BY total_bytes DESC limit 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're aggregating on the field you're trying to sort by. Those single pieces of data don't exist anymore on their own but rather as the total for each element you're grouping by.

Maybe you're trying to `order by SUM(bytes)`?

Apart from that, consider grouping by all non aggregated fields in the select statement... you're missing `stamp_updated` in the group by.

Comment: Very good point with aggregating `stamp_updated`. I'd suggest a MAX, for what the query seems to be about.

Comment: This table contains list of src and destination IP addresses and the amount of traffic that had gone through. I am trying to get the top usage over a given interval (e.g. past 7 hours)