# SQL: More efficient sql query against chinook database

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I'm practicing with the [chinook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhVjF.jpg) database.

I have to provide a query that shows which sales agent made the most in sales in 2009.

[image]

I've tried with this code in SQLite:

```
SELECT Full_Name as Best_Salesman, Max(Total_per_Agent) as Maximum_Amount               
FROM                
    (SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName|| ' '|| e.LastName as Full_Name,sum (i.total) AS Total_per_Agent
    FROM customers c, invoices i, employees e
    WHERE c.CustomerId=i.CustomerId
    AND c.SupportRepId=e.EmployeeId
    AND i.invoiceDate BETWEEN "2009-01-01" AND "2009-12-31"
    GROUP BY c.SupportRepId)
```

The database size is not large enough, so I could really use the code I already made. But, I would like to find a more efficient solution and not to use a 'SELECT/FROM/SELECT' code. In the case that the database was much larger, it would make the code more inefficient.

Any help?

Comment: I don't know if sql lite supports select top(1) {columns} but that may be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the outer query, as you can use the inner query to get the sales total for each agent, then order the result set in descending order and limit it to one row. I have not used SQLite before so I'm sorry if I don't get the syntax exactly right, but the general idea is this:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName|| ' '|| e.LastName as Full_Name,sum (i.total) AS Total_per_Agent
FROM customers c, invoices i, employees e
WHERE c.CustomerId=i.CustomerId
AND c.SupportRepId=e.EmployeeId
AND i.invoiceDate BETWEEN "2009-01-01" AND "2009-12-31"
GROUP BY c.SupportRepId 
ORDER BY Total_per_Agent DESC limit 1;
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077947/sqlite-sorting-sum-column-values) thread, you can and need to order by the alias for the aggregated column, not the original i.total column.

Comment: While the SELECT/FROM/SELECT code remains 7 ms, the new one proposes by you do it in 4 ms. Thanks for your help brothers and sisters!!!